# Program to find the inverse of polynomial

Tags: finite-field

Can anyone tell me how to find the inverse of a given polynomial using python programming?
Ex: input given is to find the inverse of (x^2 + 1) modulo (x^4 + x + 1).
the output should be : (x^3 + x + 1).

Comment: This [finite field package](https://pypi.org/project/pyfinite/) seems to have the Ffield.Inverse() method.

Answer (score 1):

To compute the invert of $P$ modulo $Q$ with $Q$ of degree $n+1$, an easy solution could be to solve a linear system with unknown:
$\lambda_0, \dots, \lambda_n$ such that
$P^{-1}= \sum \lambda_i X^i$.

Then we know $(P \cdot(\sum \lambda_i X^i) )\mod Q = 1$.
And by looking the equality for every coordinate, we have $n+1$ equations with $n+1$ unknowns. And the equations are independent if and only if $P$ is invertible in $\mathbb{Z}_p[X]/(Q\mathbb{Z}_p[X])$.

With your example $n=3$.
\begin{align}((X^2 +1) \cdot( \lambda_0 + \lambda_1 X + \lambda_2 X^2 + \lambda_3 X^3) )\mod (X^4 + X + 1) = 1 \\
\lambda_0 + \lambda_1 X + (\lambda_2+\lambda_0) X^2 + (\lambda_3+ \lambda_1) X^3  + (\lambda_2 + \lambda_3X) X^4= 1 \\
\lambda_0 + \lambda_1 X + (\lambda_2+\lambda_0) X^2 + (\lambda_3+ \lambda_1) X^3  + (\lambda_2 + \lambda_3X) (-X-1)= 1 \\
(\lambda_0-\lambda_2) + (\lambda_1- \lambda_2 - \lambda_3) X + (\lambda_2+\lambda_0-\lambda_3) X^2 + (\lambda_3+ \lambda_1) X^3 = 1 
\end{align}

If you solve the linear system, you will find the solution $\lambda_2=0$ and $\lambda_1=\lambda_3=\lambda_0=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Sagemath can solve this, and as we know the SageMath uses Python. The reverse is also possible! Install the package by;

`pip3 install sagemath`

Now we are ready to use the SageMath code

```
k = GF(2)
R.<x> = k[]
k.extension(x^4 + x + 1, 'a')
print(k)

p = (x^2 + 1)

print(p)

q = p.inverse_mod(x^4 + x + 1)

print(q)
```

However, the `R.<x> = k[]` is not parsable by python. We have to use [preparse](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/repl/sage/repl/preparse.html) to form python code.

```
preparse('R.<x> = k[]')
"R = k['x']; (x,) = R._first_ngens(1)"
```

So the python code is

```
from sage.all import *

F = GF(2)
R = F['x']; (x,) = R._first_ngens(1)
K = F.extension(x**4 + x + 1, 'a')

print(K)

p = (x**2 + 1)
print(p)
q = p.inverse_mod(x**4 + x + 1)
print(q)
```

This outputs;

```
Finite Field in a of size 2^4
x^2 + 1
x^3 + x + 1
```

---

Thanks to John Palmieri on the [preparse](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/59672/using-sagemath-finite-field-extension-on-python/)